# How to merge 2 array to result is a array?

Tags: php

I have a sample code

```
$array1 = ("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
$array2 = ("val1", "val2", "val3");
array = array_merge($array1, $array2);
```

when i `print_r($array)` is result is

```
array([0] => val1 [1] => val2 [2] => val3)
```

How to fix this error to result is:

```
array(['attr1'] => val1 ['attr2'] => val2 ['attr3'] => val3)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?php
$a = array('green', 'red', 'yellow');
$b = array('avocado', 'apple', 'banana');
$c = array_combine($a, $b);

print_r($c);
?>
```

// Output

```
Array
(
    [green]  => avocado
    [red]    => apple
    [yellow] => banana
)
```

Answer (score 1):

I think what you want is `array_combine()`. Use:

```
$array1 = ("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
$array2 = ("val1", "val2", "val3");
$array = array_combine($array1, $array2);
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if that was just a typo on your part, but you need to put the merged array back into another variable...

```
$array3=array_merge($array1,$array2);
print_r($array3)
```

Edit: the other guys are right, sorry I didn't read your question well enough. You want array_combine.

Comment: you don't see the result him needs? array_merge don't will produce the result... array_combine Yes

Answer (score 1):

Use array_combine().
More info: http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$array1 = ("attr1", "attr2", "attr3");
$array2 = ("val1", "val2", "val3");
$array = $array1 + $array2
```

Easy Peasy